# How to customize Foobar2000 icons (including main icon)?

Tags: windows, icons, foobar2000, appearance

Foobar2000 is a highly customizable player, but is it possible to customize its icons - including its main icon?

[image]

(I don't hate it, but I might want to change it, especially that multiple portable installations can be used, with various components and skins, so they might as well be differentiated by their icon.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To change the icons of the associated files (in case foobar2000 is the default music player), edit the icons pack from the folder `C:\Program Files\foobar2000\icons`
- To change the general icon, you need [`foo_UI_hacks`](http://foobar2000.ru/forum/download/file.php?id=2022&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;filename=foo_ui_hacks_2013-02-19.zip), and that will add new preferences for  Main Window and Notification Area. The same component allows adding three separate tray icons for play/pause/stop.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- In order to get some more enhancements in Windows 7, one may consider using also [this component](http://wintense.com/plugins/foo_w7shell)

[image]

[image]

- To get the same custom icon pinned to the taskbar, create a shortcut for `foobar.exe` (right-click: send to - desktop), change its icon (under its Properties) to the custom one, and then drag it to the taskbar.